# Como executar testes com Cucumber e testes unitários na mesma execução 'mvn test'?

Tags: java, testes, junit, cucumber

testes com Cucumber estou me referindo àqueles métodos anotados com @Quando, @Entao, etc. Já testes unitários, são aqueles métodos anotados com @Test, usando Mockito também.

Ao executar 'mvn test', consigo validar todos os testes com Cucumber OU todos os testes unitários, mas não os dois ao mesmo tempo! É possível fazer isso? Como?

Um fato curioso é que se eu ir até a pasta java dentro de test, colorida como verde, clicar com botao direito dentro do IntelliJ e clicar em Run all tests, ele executa todos na mesma execucao (Cucumber e unitarios).